# Is SqlDataAdapter.FillSchema("SELECT * FROM MyTable", SchemaType.Source) an expensive method?

Tags: .net, sqldataadapter, sqlclient

Often when adding data to a table I will use a SqlDataAdapter.FillSchema method to generate a table that I then populate with new rows. One of the parameters for the SqlDataAdapter is a Select statement. This select statement has no criteria so normally if run it would return all the rows in the table. Does the FillSchema somehow not actually query for all the rows and just get the schema information? Should I be adding criteria like "WHERE 1=0" so that it won't return any rows? Is this really bad practice and I should rather use a SQLCommand and an Insert statement?

```
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("MyConnectionString"),
          da As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM MyTable", cn),
          cb As New SqlCommandBuilder(da),
          t As New DataTable

        da.FillSchema(t, SchemaType.Source)

        Dim r = t.NewRow

        r("Field1") = 1
        r("Field2") = 2

        t.Rows.Add(r)
        da.Update(t)

    End Using
```

Comment: That should be ok, it should not query the table values to fill the schema. If you wanted to check yourself you could profile it with Sql Profiler.

Comment: Learn to use the USING-END USING blocks to avoid having to manually dispose your objects like that.

Comment: @Igor I used SSMS and was able to see the exact "SELECT * FROM MyTable" text show up under the Recent Expensive Queries. I'll need to learn more about profiling to understand exactly what gets returned from SQL Server.

Comment: @LarsTech I thought I had to nest all my Using statements, which made the code look goofy, now I just learned that you can comma separate them. So now that is way better.  I'll be using USING much more now. I updated the sample, is that how you would do it?